# How to change the heading of all models in django admin

Tags: django

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QH92Y.png)

I have created a model named 'Questions' in my app.Please see the attached image.
here my app name is 'polls'.Is it possible to change in admin view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change verbose_name on [app_config](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/applications/#configuring-applications)

*this works for Django 1.7+

for prior version each Model should have

```
class Meta:
   app_label = 'Not Polls'
```

set

Answer (score 0):

You must add this line to apps.py file inside Config Class
    `verbose_name = 'Text'`

For example:

```
    class PollsConfig(AppConfig):
        name = 'core'
        verbose_name = 'Your Text'
```